# Mentioning Channel with Embed Command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command where is sends in embed the channel like #test

Here is my Code

````
async def embed(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="How to Verify?", description="To Verify! Go to <!#2132103113>" , color=discord.Color.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you mention a channel, whether it is in an embed or not, you can use this format:

`<#2132103113>`

You can also use:

```py
channel = client.get_channel(2132103113)
embed=discord.Embed(title="How to Verify?", description=f"To Verify! Go to {channel.mention}" , color=discord.Color.blue())
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```